# Aborting emacs batch mode when no user input available

Tags: org-mode, batch-mode

I have a small script that runs the following command to export my org-mode agendas automatically:

```
emacs -batch -l ~/.emacs.d/init.el -eval '(org-batch-store-agenda-views)'
```

Occasionally, a required agenda file is missing or unavailable, which causes emacs to pause at the command prompt with something like the following:

```
Non-existent agenda file ~/gtd/missing.org.  [R]emove from list or [A]bort?
```

Emacs will then hang until I kill it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Is there a way to get emacs to automatically abort in batch mode if user input is not available? Or is it possible to set a timeout on the running of emacs in batch mode, so that it automatically exits after a certain period of time.

(I tried using the `timeout` shell command — e.g. `timeout 10s emacs -batch ...` — but that doesn't work either.)

Comment: You should report this to the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html) as a bug: it should not be the case that a batch function calls a function (`org-check-agenda-file`) that stops and asks the user what to do.